# Octave : difficulties to open a .csv

Tags: csv, octave

I m new on Octave and I have a problem with a .csv file.

I want to open a .csv file following these operations :

```
clear all
M = dlmread('test2.csv', '\t',1,3);
P = M(:,10);
I = M(:,8);
U = M(:,9);

Pelec = I x U;
```

The tabler M creates by this way presents only '0'. How can I load my .csv properly ? I have supposed that the first and second colonm is a problem, that is why I exclude them.

You will find the file that I use here :

[Image du fichier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpdJU.png)

Thank you for your helping, I have read a lot about dlmread function and

Comment: providing the first lines of the file you are trying to load (even truncated) would be more helpful to test some code than a link to an image

Answer (score 1):

You are using tab-delimiter in dlmread(), while your file is fixed-width (fields probably seperated with spaces - hard to see on the .png).